# .Net Core query case-insensitive string data in list from MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I have been working out for a case-insensitive search for hours and I still can`t find a solution...

I have data stored in MongoDB and formatted like this :

```
{
  id: 12345,
  name: "foo",
  area: ["US","California"],
  ...
}
```

And I wanna use query to find results, as a list, that area partially matches the area string. For example, if I want to find people who are in us, with lower case.
My method looks like this:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Restaurant>> GetByArea(string area)
{
     var result = await _context.Users
          .Find(user => user.Area.Contains(area))
          .ToListAsync();

     try
     {
          return result;
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
          return null;
     }
}
```

How should I modify my code to conform case-insensitive search? The IEqualityComparer's methods won't be translated to MongoDB query.

Comment: I'd look into MongoDB collation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it would work, but you can try to use the method `Any`:

```
var result = await _context.Users
    .Find(user => user.Area.Any(item => item.ToLower() == area.ToLower()))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you! that actually works! I was stuck on how to use StringComparer and not looked back the simple way!!

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?

```
(user => user.Area.Contains(area, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: I tried, and I think some of the methods are not supported in fluent API? I got not supported exception.